# VS Code - Unable to manage two Git Repositories on Workspace

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a Visual Studio Code Workspace composed by two folders:

```
MyProject\FrontEnd
MyProject\BackEnd
```

The workspace is properly loaded in Visual Studio Code.

Now I want to create and manage one distinct repository for each folder.

From what I saw till now, I can manage only a single repository and I can't manage the second one...

May be I'm doing a wrong procedure.

I have also tried to create a single repositoru at the root level of "MyProject" folder but If I try Visual Studio Code asks me to select one of the two subfolder.

I don't know if I'm wrong of if it is not possible to manage two repositories in one workspace.

Thanks to support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till the release: 1.22, managing two git repositories in one workspace is not possible:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_22